# Write an function that takes a string and returns the number of unique characters in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, methods, collections

I need a function using collections and maps, how can I improve this function using collection methods?
The function works but needs to be modified to import collection methods.

```
string = str(input())
check = []
unikal = []
for i in string:
    if i in unikal:
        if not (i in check):
            check.append(i)
            del unikal[unikal.index(i)]
    else:
        if not (i in check):
            unikal.append(i)

print("Number of unique characters: ", len(unikal))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want the function to do, are you just trying to find the number of unique characters in a string?

Comment: FYI there's no reason for using ```str(input())```, the built-in ```input()``` returns a string, no matter what the user types in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use list method, count() :

```
unique = [i for i in input() if string.count(i) == 1]
print(len(unique))
```